# Passport user object in request not available in getInitialProps when server is on a different port

Tags: express, graphql, next.js, passport.js, apollo-client

I have my `express` server on a different port than my client-side `nextjs` project.

I know when you have a server on the same port you can use `getRequestHandler` with `next` that passes the `user` object to be accessible with `getInitialProps` in the client-side.

```
const express = require("express");
const next = require("next");

const app = next({ dev: true });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express();

  // adds passport session
  require("./middlewares").init(server);

  const apolloServer = require("./graphql").createApolloServer();
  apolloServer.applyMiddleware({ app: server });

  server.all("*", (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res);
  });

  server.listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
});
```

My passport implementation is as follows

```
const config = require("../config");
const session = require("express-session");
const passport = require("passport");

exports.init = (server, db) => {
  require("./passport").init(passport);

  const sess = {
    name: "pid",
    secret: config.SESSION_SECRET,
    cookie: { maxAge: 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000 },
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: db.initSessionStore(),
  };

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    server.set("trust proxy", 1);
    sess.cookie.secure = true;
    sess.cookie.httpOnly = true;
    sess.cookie.sameSite = 'none';
    sess.cookie.domain = process.env.DOMAIN;
  }

  server.use(session(sess));
  server.use(passport.initialize());
  server.use(passport.session());
};
```

And running the following on the `express` server, I can see `req.user` returning the `user` object.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.user);
  next();
});
```

In a page in my `nextjs` app, in `getInitialProps` `req.user` is `undefined`

```
Home.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
  const { req } = ctx;
  const { user } = req;
  console.log(user);
  ..........
};
```

Is there a way to either access the `passport` `user` object via SSR in nextjs or a different method to authorize and user on a page?

I do have a [Github Repo](https://github.com/AaronMcCloskey/nextjs-apollo-issue) with instructions on how to run the app in the `README.md`

Comment: I just downloaded your github repo and played around a bit. There are some issues for people trying to reproduce your problem. There seems to be a minimum of 6 characters needed for the fake data username, but you supply *admin* which only has 5. Another problem is that apollo bitches, because it receives no absolute base url, because the *.env* file where it is specified is missing from the client. I tried to use `getServerSideProps` instead of `getInitialProps` in your project, but it seems like you defined `getInitialProps` somewhere extra where I am not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Passport auth doesn't seems work across port. The solution is put a ngnix in front.
[Local passport authorization on different ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37652378/local-passport-authorization-on-different-ports)