# Node js authentication in cross domain

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication, mean-stack

I am working on a **MEAN** application, I am using Angular 4 for my project. For authentication, I have implemented the Passport js [`Local-strategy`](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local). And I am maintaining persistent session using [`Express-session`](https://github.com/expressjs/session). Things are working fine till here.

**The Problem**

In the same domain `session` works fine and I am able to authenticate the user. But in cross-domain, I am not able to maintain the session. It generates a new session id for each new request in cross-domain.

I then tried [`Passport-jwt`](https://github.com/themikenicholson/passport-jwt) but the problem with it is I don't have the control over user session. I mean I can't logout the user from the server if he is inactive or even on server re-start also the `token` don't get invalid.

So in simple words, I am looking for an authentication solution in Node js (Express js) in which I can manage authentication in cross-domain.

I have already seen some blog post and SO questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19043511/passport-js-fails-to-maintain-session-in-cross-domain), but it doesn't help.

Thank you.

**EDIT**

Should I write my own code to achieve this? If so I have a plan.

My basic plan is:

1. The user will send credentials with the login request.
2. I will check for the credentials in the database. If credentials are valid, I will generate a random token and save it to the database, in the user table and the same token I will provide to the user with success response.
3. Now, with each request user will send the token and I will check the token for each request in the database. If the token is valid then I will allow the user to access the API otherwise I will generate an error with 401 status code.
4. I am using Mongoose (MongoDB) so I will be ok to check the token in each request (performance point of view).

I think this is also a good idea. I just want some suggestions, whether I am thinking in right direction or not.

What I will get with this:

1. The number of logged in user in the application (active sessions).
2. I can logout a user if he is idle for a certain interval of time.
3. I can manage multiple login session of the same user (by doing an entry in the database).
4. I can allow the end user to clear all other login sessions (like Facebook and Gmail offers).
5. Any customization related to authorization.

**EDIT 2**

Here I am shareing my `app.js` code

```
var express = require('express');
var helmet = require('helmet');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var dotenv = require('dotenv');
var env = dotenv.load();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var flash    = require('connect-flash');
var session      = require('express-session');
var cors = require('cors');

var databaseUrl = require('./config/database.js')[process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'];
// configuration 
mongoose.connect(databaseUrl); // connect to our database

var app = express();

// app.use(helmet());

// required for passport


app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept');
  if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
       res.send(200);
   } else {
       next();
   }
});


app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(session({
    secret: 'ilovescotchscotchyscotchscotch', // session secret
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    name: 'Session-Id',
    cookie: {
      secure: false,
      httpOnly: false
    }
}));


require('./config/passport')(passport); // pass passport for configuration

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/user.route');
var seeders = require('./routes/seeder.route');
var branches = require('./routes/branch.route');
var companies = require('./routes/company.route');
var dashboard = require('./routes/dashboard.route');
var navigation = require('./routes/navigation.route');
var roles = require('./routes/role.route');
var services = require('./routes/services.route');

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
// app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
app.use(flash()); // use connect-flash for flash messages stored in session

require('./routes/auth.route')(app, passport);
app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/seed', seeders);
app.use('/branches', branches);
app.use('/companies', companies);
app.use('/dashboard', dashboard);
app.use('/navigation', navigation);
app.use('/roles', roles);
app.use('/services', services);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.status(404).send({ status: 'NOT_FOUND', message: 'This resource is not available.'});
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  let errorObj = { 
    status: 'INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR',
    message: 'Something went wrong.',
    error: err.message
  };
  res.status(err.status || 500).send(errorObj);
});

module.exports = app;
```

**EDIT 3**

> For those who don't understand my problem. Explaining the problem in
>   simple words:

1. My Express server is running on port 3000.
2. In order to consume any API from the server, a user must be logged in.
3. When a user gets logged in from `localhost:3000`, the server checks the credentials(using Passport-local) and returns a token in the response header.
4. Now after login, when a user hits any API from `localhost:3000`, a predefined `Header` comes with `passport-session` and then passport verifies the user session using `req.isAuthenticated()` and all the things works as expected.
5. When a user gets logged in from `localhost:4000` and the server send a token in response header (same as `localhost:3000`).
6. When after successful login, the user hits any API from `localhost:4000` the passport js function `req.isAuthenticated()` returns `false`.
7. This was happening because in cross-domain the `cookie` doesn't go to the server we need to set `withCredentials` header to `true` at the client side.
8. I have set `withCredentials` header to `true` but still at the server the `req.isAuthenticated()` is returning `false`.

Comment: Probably the easiest solution would be to use cookies, they are “cross domain localStorage”... somewhat... https://github.com/zendesk/cross-storage On the other question, I would thing there is a solution already made, I however never looked for it, if you find it share it, thanks.

Comment: @Akxe_, My original problem is not at client-side. The problem is at `Express-session`, the server generates new session on each request if we are in cross-domain.

Comment: Oh worth mentioning... then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071969/using-express-and-node-how-to-maintain-a-session-across-subdomains-hostheaders

Comment: @Akxe, This also doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Are the domains subdomains of each other? Like example.com and blog.example.com, or are they unrelated like example.com and example.org?

Comment: No, I have two different domain. For example, one is localhost:3000, and another is localhost:4000.

Comment: Can you share some code? the "generates a new session id for each new request in cross-domain" does not seem right to me

Comment: @Khang I have shared my code, please have a look.

Comment: Please include the code you set up Passport too. From your Edit 3, I see that you assume `localhost:3000` and `localhost:4000` are different domains. They are not, the domain is `localhost` which are the same. My guess is that you set up Passport incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution to get around CORS/cookie/same-domain problems is to create proxy server that will mirror all requests from `localhost:3000/api` to `localhost:4000`, and then use `localhost:3000/api` to access the API instead of `localhost:4000`.

Best way for production deployment is to do it on your web server (nginx/apache).

You can also do it in node via `express` and `request` modules, or use some ready made middleware like this one:

https://github.com/villadora/express-http-proxy

Solution with this middleware is pretty straightforward:

```
var proxy = require('express-http-proxy');
var app = require('express')();

app.use('/api', proxy('localhost:4000'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use sessions (ie. instead of jwt, etc)  I think by default they are just in-memory so it will not work as your application scales to multiple hosts. It is easy to configure them to persist though.

See
https://github.com/expressjs/session#compatible-session-stores

Answer (score 0):

You might have tried with passport-jwt. It generates tokens as per the JWT protocol on login. Your requirement is to blacklist the generated token when you logout. To achieve that, you can create a collection in mongodb named "BlacklistToken" with fields  userid and token. When the user logs out, you can insert the token and userid in the collection. Then write a middleware to check whether the token is blacklisted or not. if it is redirect to login page.

Answer (score 0):

did you already take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Server-Side_Access_Control):

> In this case, responses can be sent back based on some considerations.
>
> If the resource in question is meant to be widely accessed (just like any HTTP resource accessed by GET), **then sending back the Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * header will be sufficient**,[...]

You may try this (allow any public IP) :

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
 res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
 res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');  // add this line  
 // res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
 res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
```

---

It is normal that the second server re-create a new session, because assuming that you use Express-session, and according to [the documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/session):

> **Session data is not saved in the cookie** itself, just the session ID. **Session data is stored server-side**.

Which mean that you need to find a way to synchronize servers session data ...
Assuming that you find a method to do that, when you will try to connect, both server will retrieve the same user session data and the second will not have to create a new session...

Comment: Yes, I am aware of it.

Comment: We can't use "*" because we are accepting cross-domain cookies so we need to take `req.headers.origin`.

Comment: Could you double check that *req.headers.origin* is really the expected  IP... It is like cross domain is not working because you restrict access to only one IP ( other domain IP ), but if you want that the client may request on both domains, all client's publics IPs need to be allowed, so "*" ... Have you try to add "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" to the "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" list ?

Comment: @A STEFANI, I have updated the question, please see my `EDIT 3`, you will understand what I want.

Comment: @ArpitMeena, I just update my answer, take a look please

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly here, you want the user's session to be stateless on the server. So that whenever the user logs in, the session can be re-used in any instance of the server when you scale your application, or even if you were to just reboot your application.

To achieve this, what you need is to configure the `express-session` with a database solution. You can do this with `mongo` using this package https://github.com/jdesboeufs/connect-mongo.

However, best practice is to use something a bit more robust for this sort of use-case, like `redis` using this package https://github.com/tj/connect-redis.