# how to remove cors error while using ajax request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cors, passport.js

I am trying to make session using `express-session` with passport in cross domain .I take help of following links
[Sending credentials with cross-domain posts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054316/sending-credentials-with-cross-domain-posts)
[Passport js fails to maintain session in cross-domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19043511/passport-js-fails-to-maintain-session-in-cross-domain/20219335)

```
**I am getting below error**
```

> Failed to load http://localhost:5000/users/login: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the
>   wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin
>   'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The
>   credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is
>   controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

here is my whole code
https://github.com/naveennsit/Cors

**client index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:5000/users/login',
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({id: 5}),
            dataType: 'json',
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true,

            },
            crossDomain: true,
            success: function () {
                console.log('success');
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log('error')
            }
        });
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**server code**
**server.js**

```
var app = require('./app');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`app is running on ${PORT}`);
})
```

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const path = require('path');

const morgan = require('morgan');
const cors = require('cors');
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require('passport');



const app = express();



// Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cors());

app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, authorization");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS");
    next();
});
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: false,
    domain: '.localhost:3000',
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie:  {
        domain: '.localhost:3000',
        maxAge: 24 * 6 * 60 * 10000
    },
}))



app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

//Routes


app.use('/users', require('./routes/user.route'))


module.exports = app;
```

**controller.js**

```
const passport = require('passport');


const passportConfig = require('../passport')
module.exports = {
    login: async (req, res, next) => {
        console.log(req.body);
        try {

            req.login(req.body.id, function () {
                res.json({message: "Registration successfully"});

            })
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }

    },

}
```

**passport.js**

```
const passport = require('passport');
passport.serializeUser(function(id, done) {
    console.log('ddd');
//    console.log(user);
    done(null, id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    console.log('deserializeUser');
    done(null, id);
    // db.User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
    //     done(err, user);
    // });
});
```

**routes**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = require('express-promise-router')();


const controller = require('../controllers/user.controller');



router.route('/login',)
    .post(controller.login)



module.exports = router;
```

I want to add session in cross-domain.I already apply cors plugin still getting same error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to allow CORS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/how-to-allow-cors)

Comment: @LaxmikantDange i already apply these thing

Comment: this is not dublicate question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the node.js package [cors](https://github.com/expressjs/cors#readme). The simplest usage is:

```
var cors = require('cors')

var app = express();

app.use(cors());
```

When using `withCredentials: true` in ajax, cors need to configure as below.

```
app.use(cors({origin: 'http://localhost:3000', credentials: true}));
```

Comment: please remove this answer

Comment: Did you configured the origin?

Comment: didn't work please checkout my code on github .if you have 2 min please let me know where I am doing wrong

Comment: You need to add credentials in access control, (see updated answer) and you are setting header manually after using cors (` res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");` that's an issue.! 
So comment ```
/* app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, authorization");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS");
    next();
}); */
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178415/discussion-between-user944513-and-mahesh-thumar).

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there to solve it. You need to send actually allowed host in `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header value and not `*`

If you want to allow for all origins, then you can include `req.headers.origin` for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header value in your CORS middleware:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", req.headers.origin);
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, authorization");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS");
    next();
});
```